# Delegate error in swift2

Tags: ios, swift

```
var mapViewDelegate: AnyObject?

init(mapView: AGSMapView, mapViewDelegate: AnyObject) {
    self.mapView = mapView
    self.mapViewDelegate = mapViewDelegate
    super.init()
}

mapView?.touchDelegate = mapViewDelegate
mapView?.layerDelegate = mapViewDelegate
```

then:

> Cannot assign value of type 'AnyObject?' to type 'AGSMapViewTouchDelegate!'

What can I do?And thank you for all the answer

Comment: maybe I'm missing something here, but is there a reason you're not just letting your `mapViewDelegate` be a `AGSMapViewTouchDelegate` instead of `AnyObject`? And if so, then maybe you could try casting it into being an `AGSMapViewTouchDelegate` before using it. Something like `if let agsMapViewTouchDelegate = mapViewDelegate as? AGSMapViewTouchDelegate { mapView?.touchDelegate = agsMapViewTouchDelegate mapView?.layerDelegate = agsMapViewTouchDelegate }` (sorry about the formatting)

Comment: what did? The `if let ... as?...` part? Great, glad we got that solved :)

Comment: mapView?.touchDelega‌​te = mapViewDelegate as? AGSMapViewTouchDeleg‌​ate,i make the Delegate target convert to type of AGSMapViewTouchDeleg‌​ate  ，different from oc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var mapViewDelegate: AnyObject?
```

It should not be like this.

It should be of belonging type of the Protocol. Not Anyobject.

Like i have a protocol named AllowNotificationDelegate.
So my delegated variable is defined as

```
weak var allowNotificationDelegate: AllowNotificationDelegate?
```

type of AllowNotificationDelegate.

so you should write

```
weak var mapViewDelegate: AGSMapViewTouchDelegate?
```

Comment: Welcome. 
Glad to help you :)